# Bigger column height and big brackets in a table

Tags: tables, spacing

I'm trying to replicate this table from this website (without AIC included): https://uc-r.github.io/model_selection

I think I've got most of it down, however, I'd like so the brackets increase in size so that that they have the full length of `1/n` for `Cp` and `BIC`. For the `Adjusted R^2`, I'd like the bracket to extend to around the entire fraction. Also I'd like the column height to become a bit greater as it is looking a bit squashed at the moment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[allow-number-unit-breaks]{siunitx}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
\caption{Summary Model Statistics for Multiple Linear Regression Model} 
\label{tab5} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lll} 
\\[-1.8ex]\toprule 
\\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Objective} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Equation} \\
\midrule \\[-1.8ex]
$C_p$ & Minimise & $C_p$ = $\frac{1}{n}$ $(RSS + 2d\hat{\sigma})$ \\
Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC) & Minimise & $BIC$ = $\frac{1}{n}$ $(RSS + log(n)d\hat{\sigma}^2)$ \\
Adjusted $R^2$ & Maximise & Adj. $R^2$ = $1 - (\frac{RSS/n-d-1}{TSS/(n-1)})$  \\
\bottomrule \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example removes most of the manual oddities (e.g., `\\[-1.8ex]`)
and add some fine-tuning:

- Normal table rows are used, but the formula lines are separated by an additional space (`booktab`'s `\addlinespace`).
- The table header are left-aligned, because all cells in the body are left-aligned.
- `\left(...\right)` is use in the last cell to match the size of the fences to the fraction.
- Normal math mode spacing (`$a = b$` instead of `$a$ = $b$`).
- `\log` instead of `log` to get the normal upright form.
- `\mathrm` or `\text` (`amsmath` or `amstext`) for the text variables `RSS`, `BIC` , and `TSS`.
- I do not know the purpose of `\extracolsep{5pt}`. If it is used in all tables, then ok. But if it is used to stretch the table to the line width, then `\extracolsep{\fill}` with `\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}` calculates the needed amount automatically.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Summary Model Statistics for Multiple Linear Regression Model}
  \label{tab5}
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lll}
    \toprule
    Statistic & Objective & Equation \\
    \midrule
    $C_p$ & Minimise &
    $C_p = \frac{1}{n} (\text{RSS} + 2d\hat{\sigma})$ \\
    \addlinespace
    Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC) & Minimise &
    $\text{BIC} = \frac{1}{n} (\text{RSS} + \log(n)d\hat{\sigma}^2)$ \\
    \addlinespace
    Adjusted $R^2$ & Maximise &
    Adj.\@
    $R^2 = 1 - \left(\frac{\text{RSS}/n-d-1}{\text{TSS}/(n-1)}\right)$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 4):

You should not adjust row heights by hand, but use mark-up. For instance,  don't add  `\\[-1.8ex]` as though you were using Word. Also, every atom of a maths formula doesn't have to be between `$  $`: a single pair fo the whole formula will do.

For vertical padding of rows I use the `cellspace` package, which defines *minimal* distances between the top of a cell and the bottom of the above cell, and similarly between  the bottom of a cell and the top of the below cell, in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S`   (or `C` if you load `siunitx`). For the vertical distance between table and  caption above table, simply load the `caption` package. Finally, I'd replace the `\frac` command within the table (too small) with the `\mfrac` from `nccmath` (medium-sized fraction).

For the size of the parentheses, you can use the pairs `\bigl/r`, `\Bigl/r`, `\biggl/r`, `\Biggl/r`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{4pt}
\usepackage[allow-number-unit-breaks]{siunitx}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
\caption{Summary Model Statistics for Multiple Linear Regression Model}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\label{tab5}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}*{3}{Cl}}
\toprule
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Objective} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Equation} \\
\midrule
$C_p$ & Minimise & $C_p = \mfrac{1}{n}\bigl(RSS + 2d\hat{\sigma}\bigr)$ \\
Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC) & Minimise & $BIC = \mfrac{1}{n}\bigl(RSS + \log(n)d\hat{\sigma}^2\bigr)$ \\
Adjusted $R^2$ & Maximise & Adj. $R^2 = 1 - \Bigl(\mfrac{RSS/n-d-1}{TSS/(n-1)}\Bigr)$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, a peaceful and happy Easter to you and your loved ones. Upvote you.

Answer (score 3):

The following MWE contains two alternative solutions. For the round brackets around the fraction, I used `\left(` and `\right)`. For additional row heights, I used `\\[5pt]`. The second example also aligns the equations in the last column with respect to the `=` sign.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp] 
\centering 
\caption{Summary Model Statistics for Multiple Linear Regression Model} 
\label{tab5} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lll} 
\\[-1.8ex]\toprule 
\\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Objective} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Equation} \\
\midrule \\[-1.8ex]
$C_p$ & Minimise & $C_p$ = $\frac{1}{n}$ $(RSS + 2d\hat{\sigma})$ \\[5pt]
Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC) & Minimise & $BIC$ = $\frac{1}{n}$ $\left(RSS + log(n)d\hat{\sigma}^2\right)$ \\ [5pt]
Adjusted $R^2$ & Maximise & Adj. $R^2$ = $1 - \left(\frac{RSS/n-d-1}{TSS/(n-1)}\right)$  \\
\bottomrule \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp] 
\centering 
\caption{Summary Model Statistics for Multiple Linear Regression Model} 
\label{tab5} 
\begin{tabular}{@{}llr@{ = }l@{}} 
\\[-1.8ex]\toprule 
\\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Objective} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Equation} \\
\midrule \\[-1.8ex]
$C_p$ & Minimise & $C_p$ & $\frac{1}{n}$ $(RSS + 2d\hat{\sigma})$ \\[5pt]
Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC) & Minimise & $BIC$ & $\frac{1}{n}$ $\left(RSS + log(n)d\hat{\sigma}^2\right)$ \\ [5pt]
Adjusted $R^2$ & Maximise & Adj. $R^2$ & $1 - \left(\frac{RSS/n-d-1}{TSS/(n-1)}\right)$  \\
\bottomrule \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]